# nativeQuery is not recognised in Query params

Tags: java, sql, spring

I am trying to execute sql query using spring JpaRespository.I am using "nativeQuery = true" in Query param.But it is showing following error

'The attribute nativeQuery is undefined for the annotation type Query'

This is my test class

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.js.domain.Test;


@Repository(value="testRepo")
public interface TestRepo extends JpaRepository<Hierarchy,Integer>{
    @Query(value = "select * from test", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Hierarchy> findAllList();

}
```

I am not able to find what I am missing here.

Comment: which version do you use for spring-data-jpa

Comment: Looks like `nativeQuery` has been supported since 1.1 from 2012, so are you really using a 1.0 version? Note that latest release is 1.10.